# DllNotFoundException: libgfxunity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, scaleform

I'm new to unity and I am trying to use a plugin named Scaleform and I'm following the steps indicated in readme file, I've created a new project, imported the plugin, selected Main Camera object and attached the specified script to it, but when I want to play, I get this error:

DllNotFoundException: libgfxunity3d
SFCamera.OnDestroy () (at Assets/Plugins/SF/SFCamera.cs:163)

I googled and all I got was this: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Scaleform-Unity-Development/dll-not-found-exception/td-p/4242779

I've downloaded and installed DirectX too, but still no change! :(

Does anyone know what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this problem on Windows. Ultimately, reinstalling the DirectX runtime did fix it for us (the person who had the problem was missing the d3dx9_43.dll that the Scaleform dll depends on).

You might also check and make sure you have put the right key into the appropriate location in your inherited camera script. (In the example, I believe it is called MyCamera.cs.)

Finally, you should check that your build target matches the version of the Scaleform trial you have installed. If your Unity build setting is Android, for example, you need to have the Android runtime for Windows, not the Windows runtime proper.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Depends application from http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and loaded libgfxunity3d.dll. I was missing msvcr100.dll, IEShims.dll and wer.dll. I threw those dlls into the System32 directory and my program ran great. Hope this helps!